# Combined and copy paste Data from multiple excel file to another is not works correctly

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

So First of all I have main excel file called `Cluster_Cell.xlsx` that's I need to populate it from another excel file called `GU EP20191016171519.xlsx` contains 3 main sheets that I want to copy data form it these sheets called `GSM_CDDData`, `UMTS_CDDData`, and `UMTS_CDDData` from Column called `CELLNAME` and this column name is atatic for all excel files I have.......

Now this is the part that copying the data in column named CELLNAME to master sheet Cluster_Cell.xlsxso the master sheet also have a column called system that's I need also to populate with data related to those three sheets for example, I have three sheets named by GSM_CDDData, UMTS_CDDData, and LTE_CDDData..... So now I need to populate rows as values GSM related for rows in column CELLNAME in sheet GSM_CDDData, need to populate rows as values UMTS related to sheet_name called UMTS_CDDData, and need also to populate rows as values UMTS related to sheet_name called LTE_CDDData....

and here's my code

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

mydir = (os.getcwd()).replace('\\', '/') + '/'

cluster_cell = pd.read_excel(r'' + mydir + 'Cluster_Cell.xlsx', usecols=['CELLNAME'], encoding='latin-1')

GUL_EP_GSM = pd.read_excel(r'' + mydir + 'GU EP20191016171519.xlsx', sheet_name="GSM_CDDData", usecols=['CELLNAME'],
                           encoding='latin-1')


GUL_EP_UMTS = pd.read_excel(r'' + mydir + 'GU EP20191016171519.xlsx', sheet_name="UMTS_CDDData", usecols=['CELLNAME'],
                            encoding='latin-1')


GUL_EP_LTE = pd.read_excel(r'' + mydir + 'GU EP20191016171519.xlsx', sheet_name="LTE_CDDData", usecols=['CELLNAME'],
                           encoding='latin-1')

#converting to float
GUL_EP_GSM=GUL_EP_GSM.astype(int)
GUL_EP_UMTS=GUL_EP_UMTS.astype(int)
GUL_EP_LTE=GUL_EP_LTE.astype(int)

#print dataframes astype float
print(cluster_cell)
print(GUL_EP_GSM)
print(GUL_EP_UMTS)
print(GUL_EP_LTE)
#creating appended_cell_name dataframe
appended_cell_name = pd.DataFrame({'CELLNAME': cluster_cell['CELLNAME'] & GUL_EP_GSM['CELLNAME'] & GUL_EP_UMTS['CELLNAME'] & GUL_EP_LTE['CELLNAME']})

#creating mask with isin
mask1 = appended_cell_name['CELLNAME'].isin(GUL_EP_GSM['CELLNAME'])
mask2 = appended_cell_name['CELLNAME'].isin(GUL_EP_UMTS['CELLNAME'])
mask3 = appended_cell_name['CELLNAME'].isin(GUL_EP_LTE['CELLNAME'])

#using np.select
cond=[mask1,mask2,mask3]
values=['GSM','UMTS','LTE']
appended_cell_name['system']=np.select(cond,values)

#print appended_cell_name
print(appended_cell_name)
#save in excell
appended_cell_name.to_excel("Cluser_Cell_Final.xlsx", index=False)
```

and the output for

```
print(cluster_cell)
print(GUL_EP_GSM)
print(GUL_EP_UMTS)
print(GUL_EP_LTE)
```

```
      CELLNAME
0        10709
1        10710
2        10711
3        11340
4        11341
...        ...
2347   2304376
2348   2304377
2349   2205890
2350   2205891
2351   2205892

[2352 rows x 1 columns]
     CELLNAME
0       10169
1       10170
2       10171
3       10349
4       10350
..        ...
124     54237
125     54996
126     54997
127     54998
128     55966

[129 rows x 1 columns]
     CELLNAME
0     1106382
1     1106383
2     1106384
3     1019810
4     1019811
..        ...
262   1102891
263   1102892
264   1018393
265   1018394
266   1018395

[267 rows x 1 columns]
     CELLNAME
0     2002388
1     2002389
2     2002390
3     2100118
4     2100119
..        ...
538   2304376
539   2304377
540   2205890
541   2205891
542   2205892
```

and the output of
`print(appended_cell_name)`

```
      CELLNAME system
0         True      0
1        False      0
2         True      0
3        False      0
4         True      0
...        ...    ...
2347     False      0
2348     False      0
2349     False      0
2350     False      0
2351     False      0

[2352 rows x 2 columns]
```

So my Expected value for `appended_cell_name`

is

```
      CELLNAME system
0        10709   GSM
1        10710   GSM
2        10711   GSM
3        11340   GSM
4        11341   GSM
...        ...    ...
2347     2304376 LTE
2348     2304377 LTE
2349     2205890 LTE
2350     2205891 LTE
2351     2205892 LTE
```

So the main idea is to get all the data required from all 4 `dataframe` to one excel file called `Cluser_Cell_Final.xlsx`

Comment: Combine your data to a dictionary and then write them to the file

Comment: @Kostas Charitidis could you specify with examples :)

Comment: @Kostas Charitidis what do you mean exactly ,Combine your data to a dictionary?